# Output command to null

Tags: bash, azure-devops, null

I am using Azure pipelines variables to construct a set of parameters for a command. The type of variable I must use for Azure pipelines is in macro format (like `$(var)`), you can see the details of it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax

If `$(var)` does not contain a value, instead of printing "nothing", it will print `$(var)`

When I run my command and that value isn't passed in, an error prompts on the screen that command was not found. At the moment it's not a big deal, it doesn't error my following set of commands, but I was hoping to suppress it at the very least.

```
VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY="$(TERRAFORMDESTROY)"

if [ ${#VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY} -ge 1 ]; then
  VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY="yes"
else
  VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY="no"
fi
```

In the logs output it will print `/vsts/_work/_temp/4e426335-0930-4375-b05c-c4dbbcb38139.sh: line 5: TERRAFORMDESTROY: command not found`

I have tried `VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY="$(TERRAFORMDESTROY)" > /dev/null 2>&1`, but because `> /dev/null 2>&1` is not inside the brackets (), it will not output the result to null. And it **cannot** be inside the brackets due to how Azure YAML variables work.

Can anyone suggest anything to suppress the `command not found` output for me, please?

Comment: What about just `VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY='$(TERRAFORMDESTROY)'` followed by `if [[ VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY = '$(''TERRAFORMDESTROY'')'' ]]; then VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY="nothing"; fi` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest anything to suppress the command not found output for me, please?

Suppress the group error message

```
{ VAR_TERRAFORMDESTROY="$(TERRAFORMDESTROY)"; } > /dev/null 2>&1
```